# Catch exception in sharp

Tags: exception, f#, arguments, try-catch

I have made a program where the user can typ commandos in terminal, but when the user type "quit" there is an exception. How do I catch it? Code below is just a snippet, because my code is really long.

```
  let mutable input = ""
  while myTurn = true do 
  input <- System.Console.ReadLine()
  match input with
  |_ when input = "quit" -> (myTurn <- false)
  |_ -> printfn "Incorrect input"
```

Right now, when I type "quit" my terminal gives an System.IndexOutOfRangeException
But if I change "quit" to any other word it works. Is there any way to get it to work with the word quit?

Comment: Please share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: What I can see from the updated code is incomplete pattern match on `startPos, endPos` but it still not reproducing IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't compile (myTurn, startPos, endPos are not defined), so no, it's not really an MRE as requested by Sergey Berezovskiy. Even if your code is modified to

```
let mutable myTurn = true
let mutable input = ""
while myTurn = true do 
    input <- System.Console.ReadLine()
    match input with
    |_ when input = "quit" -> (myTurn <- false)
    |_ -> printfn "Incorrect input"
```

it doesn't throw an exception when typing "quit". So I can't help you track down the exception.

However, what you actually did ask was how you catch an exception, and for that you will need a `try ... with ...`. For instance

```
try potentiallyThrowingFunction "abc" 123
with e -> printfn "Oh snap!"
```

will catch any exception and print something to the console. The exception-handling path needs to return the same type as the try-path, so if `potentiallyThrowingFunction` returns an `int`, the exception handling code needs to return an `int` as well (or throw a new exception or rethrow the original).

Actually with `try ... with ...` you can pattern match on exceptions, if you want to handle different exceptions differently; e.g.

```
try potentiallyThrowingFunction "abc" 123
with 
    | :? System.ArgumentException as e -> 
        printfn "Oh dang! ArgumentException: %s" e.Message
    | :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException as e ->
        printfn "Woops, IndexOutOfRangeException: %s" e.Message
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew this way to handle it, but it worked :)

Comment: @AlphaList catching exceptions is good, but preventing them is much better

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you were also right :) I have now fixed my problem, so catching exceptions is not necessary :D